# Tkinter Button Causing Infinite Loop

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter, infinite-loop

I am very new to coding and am currently trying to create a game. I have been working a simple code to handle the player's death using tkinter frames and buttons in python. When using tk.Button(command = lambda: self.new()) my code produces an infinite amount of my death popup. Is there a way to fix this? The line of question is with configure = ... . Without this line deny = ... works fine.

```
 def handle_death(self):
    death = tk.Tk()
    death.title("You Have Died")
    label = tk.Label(death, text="Would You Like to Restart?")
    label.pack(side=tk.TOP, pady=10, padx=10)
    death_button = tk.Frame(death)
    deny = tk.Button(death_button, text="No", command=lambda: [self.close(), death.destroy()])
    configure = tk.Button(death_button, text="Yes", command=lambda: [self.new(), death.destroy()])
    configure.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    deny.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    death_button.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
 def new(self):
    """ Creates a new game."""
    self._world = World((GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT), BLOCK_SIZE)
    load_simple_world(self._world)
    self._world.add_player(self._player, 250, 150)
    self._hot_bar.select((0, 0))
    starting_inventory = [
        ((1, 5), Stack(Item('dirt'), 10)),
        ((0, 2), Stack(Item('wood'), 10)),
    ]
    self._inventory = Grid(rows=3, columns=10)
    for position, stack in starting_inventory:
        self._inventory[position] = stack

    self._health = 1
    self._food = 1
    self._update_health(self._health)
    self._update_food(self._food)
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer with the code you have currently provided, since we do not have any knowledge of what `self.new()` does. I changed `self.new()` and `self.close()` to `print()` and the code worked perfectly fine, if you could provide code for `self.new()` then I, or someone else, could maybe help fix the issue you have.

Comment: here is my self.new() function. At the moment it is just resetting the values i have set to create the world. I placed it as an edit to the post

Comment: unfortunately the added `self.new()` code does not help, it seems your overall program is quite large and would be hard for me to debug here. However I can tell you my general sense of what the issue is. My general sense of the issue is that the class contains a value, or a field that when you run `self.new()` triggers the class to again run the `handle_death()` method. For example your class might have a health field (something like `self.health`) which might trigger `handle_death` when it is equal to 0, so one thing I might do first is update `health` and `food` first.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've been given some of these files from a friend to structure the basics so i can then create the world and all basic functions as i am reasonably new to coding. Hopefully i can stop this from running infinitely.